# How to check a key/method on a object which can be hash as well as another class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Lets say we have two classes:

```
class Test
end

class Test2
   def a
   end
end
```

and say we have a variable var which can point to an object of these class or a Hash, so:

```
var = Test.new
```

or

```
var = Test1.new
```

or

```
 var = {"a" => 1}
```

Now we need to ensure that we call 'a' on 'var' only if its allowed (i.e. it should not be called in case it points to Test). 
So, if I do:

```
var.a
```

it gives an error in case var points to Test object. Is there any way we can prevent the error? (Any other solution apart from doing **.is_a?** test ?)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [respond_to?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F) to check if you can call the method on the object:

```
var.a if var.respond_to? :a
```

Comment: it will work if using [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html). If not you'll need to check if the key is present with `var.key?('a')`

Comment: Well, then the same problem :). doing respond_to? will not work for hash while .key? will give an error with Test class. Any way we can handle both ?

Answer (score 1):

Strange questions lead to nasty answers. But at least it's working:

```
def a(test)
  (test.respond_to?(:a) ? test.a : nil) ||
  (test.respond_to?('has_key?') && test.has_key?('a') ? test['a'] : nil)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rescue from error, and return a default value, something like this

```
result = var.a rescue ""
```

Here blank string is used as default for illustration purposes, you can pick a reasonable default for your case